# 301 Redirect Multiple Url using .htaccess Magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect, 301-redirect

I'm trying to **301** redirect multiple urls to new url.

Using **.htaccess** File.

What changes i have to make in **.htaccess**

Comment: Have you tried this RewriteRule ^oldpage newpage [R=301,L]

Comment: no i have no idea about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on

redirect 301 /old_url new_url with full path
......
```

**You can set multiple redirects Like this**

Comment: thnk you... work perfectly :)

Comment: most welcome....

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .htaccess file replace the old and new URL for each one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^venia-accessories/venia-belts.html http://magento.com/venia-accessories/venia-jewelry.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: how can add multiple redirect ?

Comment: So you can copy the same and replace with old and new URL. Are you looking for something different and short way?